# Is there an equivalent to git's "describe" function for Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I'm currently adding packaging to a something that is maintained in Mercurial. Currently the version is defined in the Makefile. I would like to change this so I can build daily packages or properly versioned packages.

Git provides a use "describe" function that can give you a description of the closest tagged build and current revision. For example if I run this in the kernel:

```
git describe HEAD
```

GIT returns:

```
v3.0-rc7-68-g51414d4
```

telling me that the revision is later than v3.0-rc7, with a git commitish of 51414d4

Is there something similar I can do in Mercurial?

Comment: For those of us that doesn't know git, but does know Mercurial, could you outline what you want output and why? It would increase the likelihood of someone being able to answer a lot.

Comment: Dear OP:  If you have time, please move the checkmark from the older answer to the newer answer.  The newer answer is better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a close emulation of `git describe`:

```
hg log -r . -T "{latesttag}{sub('^-0-.*', '', '-{latesttagdistance}-m{node|short}')}"
```

The `{sub(...)}` function ensures that a working copy that's exactly at tag `v0.1.0` will show up as `v0.1.0` and not `v0.1.0-0-m123456789abc`.

Note that the `m` before the hash is for **m**ercurial, similar to the way `git describe` uses a `g` for **g**it.

For convenience, create an alias by adding the following to your `~/.hgrc`:

```
[alias]
describe = log -r . -T "{latesttag}{sub('^-0-.*', '', '-{latesttagdistance}-m{node|short}')}"
```

Then use the alias by simply typing `hg describe`.

If you'd like to emulate `git describe --dirty`, things get even messier – but you can still hide it all in an hg alias:

```
[alias]
describe = !
    dirtymark=;
    case " $1 " in " --dirty ") dirtymark=-dirty; ;; esac;
    echo $($HG log -r . --template "{latesttag}-{latesttagdistance}-m")$($HG id -i) |
        sed -r -e "s/\+\$/${dirtymark}/" -e 's/-0-m[[:xdigit:]]+//'
```

Now running `hg describe --dirty` will produce strings like:

1. `v0.1.0`
2. `v0.1.0-dirty`
3. `v0.1.0-1-mf6caaa650816`
4. `v0.1.0-1-mf6caaa650816-dirty`

Omitting the `--dirty` option means that you'll never get a `-dirty` suffix like (2) and (4), even when the working copy contains uncommitted changes.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe something like this?

```
hg log -r . --template '{latesttag}-{latesttagdistance}-{node|short}\n'
```

Of course you should make an alias for that with [AliasExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/AliasExtension).

Note however, unlike "git describe", this command will *always* show the "latesttagdistance" and "node|short" parts, instead of omitting them when latesttagdistance is 0.

Comment: Also probably doable with revsets.

Comment: Is this string guaranteed to be a valid refspec like is true with `git describe`?